# Promise.all but in interval, how to achieve it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I want to upload 20 photos to imgur at once. But I want to do in certain time gap between each upload. I was using `Promise.all([...listof20promises])`. But now I want to do api calls in interval of 1 second, and also I should be able to get response in the form of `.then((responseArray)=>...)` like we get in `Promise.all`.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Don't use Promise.all, put them in a loop and `await` each

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `async`/`await` and a normal loop with a delay between each iterations, for example:

```
const delay = t => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t));

const uploadAll = async files => {
  const results = [];

  for (const file in files) {
     if (results.length) {
        await delay(1000);  // 1 second
     }
     const response = await uploadFile(file);
     results.push({ file, response });
     
  }

  return results;
}
```

And use it as

```
uploadAll([ file1, file2, file3, ... ]).then(results => {

   // results[0] = { file, response }  where file === file1
   // results[1] = { file, response }  where file === file2
   // ...

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows:

```js
async function upload(files) {
  while (files.length) {
    await Promise.all(files.splice(0, 20));
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  }
}

upload([...]);
```

Remember that `splice` will mutate your array. If you don't want that, you can use `slice` like below:

```js
async function upload(files) {
  let i = 0;
  while (i < files.length) {
    await Promise.all(files.slice(i, i += 20));
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  }
}

upload([...]);
```

Comment: I might understand your question in a wrong way. I thought you wanted to do chunks of request, 20req/s, fyi to prevent misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the delay to be between one upload start to the next upload start, you can map the files, use a delay promise (taken from [Yanick Rochon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73901054/5157454)) with the index of the current file * 1000 as the timeout, and then call the upload:

```
const delay = t => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t));

const uploadAll = files => Promise.all(
  files.map((file, i) =>
    delay(i * 1000).then(() => uploadFile(file))
  )
);
```

The main difference between [Yanick Rochon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73901054/5157454) and mine, is that in his answer the next upload would start 1 second after the previous call ended, while this code would dispatch the calls within 1 second of each other, even if the previous call is still pending.

Comment: any chances of memory leak here?

Comment: Why do you suspect a memory leak?

Comment: if the api call fails, the timeout can keep running in backgroud, if it happens for many api calls, it could be a problem. maybe i'm wrong

Comment: All `setTimeout` calls are started before any API call happens. All of the would end, and would issue API calls. If the at least one api call happens, the promise generated by `Promise.all()` would be rejected immediately, but it won't cancels the other API calls.